# Getting back my output

Tags: arm, implementation, hardware-acceleration, cortex-m

I am trying to create a hardware accelerator for a cryptography application SHA256 
first I am using a Nexys4 FPGA as platform and a Cortex-m0 as a processor with AHBlite bus system.
i created a simple accelerator that adds two integer using a hardware accelerator then i called the output of my accelerator using these instructions

```
volatile unsigned int regSHA2 __attribute__((at(0x59000000)))...
main{ 
*(volatile unsigned int *)regSHA2= a;
*(volatile unsigned int *)regSHA2= b;
c = *(volatile signed int *)regSHA2;
```

All is fine with the adder accelerator . However, when i use the same thing with my SH2 accelerator i get the last inpout that i sent to the accelerator ...although the result of the simulation are correct i get my encrypted message but i can't get it back to my software application

Comment: If all you're doing in software is reading from an address, then it's not likely to be the software at fault. In your example code you don't give time for your accelerator to compute, does it happen in a single clock cycle?

Comment: i gave him all the needed time but it's the same thing as if the accelerator don't write the output in the defined register